# Homework for Java 1

Tags: loops, java.util.scanner

1. Write a program that asks the user for a number greater than 5 and prints all values between 1 and n that are multiples of 5 (i.e. evenly divisible by 5).
2. Write a program that prompts the user for an integer n between 1 and 100. If the number is outside the range, it prints an error.

The program computes and prints at the end two things: a.The sum of the numbers from 1 to n. b.The average of the numbers from 1 to n.

using Scanner

Question 1 I have and my code runs perfect. However I am stuck on the second half of the second problem.. Please help. Below is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a interger between 1 and 100.  ");
    int n= keyboard.nextInt();

    if ( n<1 || n > 100){
        System.out.println("No! Enter a number between 1 and 100.  ");
        n=keyboard.nextInt();

       for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
```

Comment: Can you please make your question a bit clear. The part after 2nd question is a bit confusing i.e. the program that computes two things.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, you just need a while loop instead of the if statement.

```
while ( n < 1 || n > 100){
        System.out.println("No! Enter a number between 1 and 100.  ");
        n=keyboard.nextInt();
    }
```